# Heroku Postgres auto backup not working

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I've created an app on heroku with two postgresql databases, and set up an automatic backup with the command:

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups:auto-month
```

But the backups are not being created. Am I missing something else?

Edit:
I was suggested to create promote a default database, but this would make the backup work only for one database. How do I enable the backups for both databases?

Answer (score 1):

With the pgbackups auto plans, backups are taken of the database pointed at by `DATABASE_URL` in your config. Is any of those databases `DATABASE_URL`? If not, promote one of them, your primary, with `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<color> -a <app>`, and backups should be taken nightly.

In addition to these backups, physical snapshots of all databases are taken nightly, which in addition to WAL archival are the best way to do disaster recovery, especially as your database grows in size. Think of pgbackups dumps/restores as a way of exporting and importing data, not a DR tool. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection

Comment: I see. But if set my DATABASE_URL, I can only select one of my databases, right? How do I enable automatic backups for both of them?